# How to reset Ubuntu to default settings?

Tags: software-center

I purchased a laptop with Ubuntu downloaded on it. It has the old users information on it and I would like to "Factory reset" the software so its like I just downloaded Ubuntu...

Answer (score 0):

1. Download Ubuntu.
2. Boot from your install medium.
3. Install Ubuntu.

Ignore what is on the computer now - you do not care.

Comment: will all the old software and stuff go away?

Comment: Format all the partitions.